# MIPS assembly language multiplication

Tags: assembly, mips

I am going to write multiplication the number of the device screen.

```
cout<<"Height of the device screen: 960 "<<endl;
cout<< "Width of the device screen: 640 "<<endl;
int result;
result=960*640;
cout<<"The result of the Iphone 4S in pixel: "<<result;
```

Like the c++ code above, but I really not sure what I did right or wrong. I need someone to help me. MIPS assembly language is kind of really new to me.``

```
.data
str1: .asciiz "Height of the device screen: 960 "
str2: .asciiz "Width of the device screen: 640 "
str3: .asciiz "The result of the Iphone 4S in pixel: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:
li $v0,4 #system call code for print string
la $a0,str1 #address of str1
syscall #print str1

#get the first number from the user, put into $s0
li $v0,960 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.

move $s0,$v0 #move the number read into $s0

#read input string for str2
li $v0,4  #system call code for print string
la $a0,str2 #address of str2
syscall #print str2

#get the second number from the user, put into $s1
li $v0,640 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.

move $s1,$v0 #move the number read into $s0

#do the calculation 
mul $s2,$s0,$s1 # s2 is the register to store $s0 and $s1 from the user input.

#read print string for st3
li $v0,4 #system call code for print string
la $a0,str3 #address of str3
syscall

#print width*height
li $v0,1
move $a0,$s2 #move the result of multiplication into $a0 to print
syscall
exist
```

Answer (score 1):

```
li $v0,960 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.
# ...
#get the second number from the user, put into $s1
li $v0,640 #system call for read input
syscall #read integer into $v0 from console.
```

960 is most definitely not the system call 'read' number and neither is 640. Consult your OS documentation.